# FormatException was unhandled by user code (string format is not in correct format)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Converting the Value of SQL Field from numeric type to double.
Input string was not in a correct format.
Can someone help me solve this? Thanks in Advance!

Declaration of new List:

```
public class OTTotal
{
public double OTPLAN;
public double OTACT;
}
```

then I have this code to pass the Value of database fields to those public variables.

```
            mylist.Add(new OTTotal
            {

                OTAct = double.Parse(dr["OT"].ToString()) /*+ double.Parse(dr["SH"].ToString()) + double.Parse(dr["SHtwo"].ToString())*/,
                OTPlan = double.Parse(dr["POT"].ToString())


            });
```

also this code was highlighted when i run the program and says incorrect format.

[image: This is the Error of my COde]

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTotalOverTime]
    @grpID as INT = 0,
    @date as DATE = '2018/3/1'
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(a.Overtime) as OT, SUM(a.PlanOt) as POT, SUM(a.SunHoliday) as SH, SUM(a.SunHoliday2) as SHtwo FROM tblTimesheet a JOIN userinfo b on a.empID = b.empID   JOIN tblGroup c on b.groupNo = c.groupID
            WHERE YEAR(a.tsDate) =  YEAR(@Date) AND MONTH(a.tsDate) = MONTH(@date) AND c.groupID = CAST(@grpID AS VARCHAR)

END
```

Comment: Are you sure, `dr["OT"]` and `dr["POT"]` have correct double values?

Comment: I do check it in my sql table and all the values are in double.

Comment: Check not table value, but in code

Comment: that was the code sir. as you can see, i tried to parse it as double also the variables that will catch the values of database field is in double.

Comment: Debug it then let us know what is the value of `dr["OT"]` and `dr["POT"]`.

Comment: i try it in immediate window sir, the return value has a double quote..

Comment: Also Sir, if I change the Double onto String, it work fine, but the value of other columns did not add with the OT.

Comment: "...value has a double quote". Are you saying that the value is shown as `""` (an empty string)? If so, that does not represent a double. I won't ask "Is the column nullable?" because (if I'm understanding your first comment correctly) you've said you checked your table has a double in each row. Have you used a left join to the table with that column?

Comment: Are you talking about my Store Procedure Sir? do you want me to paste it in here?

Comment: That is my Stored Proc. Sir. please check it, if i have a mistake.

Comment: and Sir, the column also is nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my Problem. I think the main problem is I have a Empty Value in my column that is why it cannot be converted to double. 
But Thank you all for giving me a hint to solve it :)

So this is the counter measure to solve my Problem.

```
  mylist.Add(new OTTotal
                {

                    OTAct = (dr["OT"].ToString() == ""? 0.0 : double.Parse(dr["OT"].ToString())) + (dr["SH"].ToString() == "" ? 0.0 : double.Parse(dr["SH"].ToString())) + (dr["SHtwo"].ToString() == "" ? 0.0 : double.Parse(dr["SHtwo"].ToString())),
                    OTPlan = (dr["POT"].ToString() == "" ? 0.0 : double.Parse(dr["POT"].ToString()))

            });
```

Thanks Everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Convert.ToDouble(dr["OT"]);`

Comment: In this case, you should display the contents of dr ["OT"], ToString () and dr ["POT"]. ToString () before passing it to the variable and ensure that they contain the correct number and format.

Comment: When I say format I mean separator of miles and decimal. Example: 100.00 or 100,00 Some culture references such as "fr-FR" can not do the conversion.
For this case use: System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo ("en-US");